# ConcurrentModificationException when removing an object from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

my classes:

```
class Game{
     ArrayList<Block> blocks;
public ArrayList<Block> getBlocks(){return blocks;};
}
class Block{
    if(conditon) {
    game.getBlocks().remove(this);
}
}
```

I have these classes, the ArrayList contains over 10 Block instances, if the condition for remove the current block in the Block class is true, i need remove this block from the ArrayList, but i got the Exception..

Comment: Please share a short complete example that produces the exception.

Comment: Paste the title of your question in google, and click on the first link it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While iterating the `Arraylist`, you are not allowed to remove any item. If you want to remove an item while iteration, you can add removed item into newly created `ArrayList` say,. 
`willBeRemovedList` after iteration completed you can remove all of them at a time.

Answer (score 3):

`ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown by iterator because you modified a list and he can't get `nextElement` because he doesn't know what really happened to list he is iterating over.

```
for (Block block : blocks) {
  blocks.remove(block);
}
```

This will throw exception when `for` loop tries to get next element of modified list, since `Iterator` is instantiated in the beginning of looping through list, iterator will be unable to choose right next element and will throw exception.

You can however remove current element from list you are iterating, but it should be done though `Iterator` itself. You would do something like this:

```
for (Iterator<Block> iterator = blocks.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); iterator.next()){
  iterator.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [**`ArrayList class`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) cleanly tells us the reason and how to avoid it:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   **iterator's own remove or add methods**, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If a fail-fast iterator detects
that a modification has been made during iteration, it throws
`ConcurrentModificationException`, which is an unchecked exception. It is highly probable that you are iterating and modifying your collection in the same loop.

Also, the collections classes in the `java.util` package all return fail-fast iterators,
which means that they assume a collection will not change its contents during
the time a thread is iterating through its contents.